# How can I determine a statistically valid pass/fail cut-off for a series of scores, while minimizing both false negatives and false positives?

Tags: standard-deviation

I have 13,378 documents. An algorithm has compared their contents against a specific topic, and has generated a score indicating the level of confidence (in percent) that Document X is somehow related to Topic X.

This means I have 13,378 scores from 0.0 to 1.0.  I need to figure out if a document is actually related ("pass") or if it's unrelated ("fail").

Here's a chart of what the scores look like:

[image]

Is there some statistical method which would help me determine a reasonable cut-off? Remember, *every* document has a score, even those which are totally unrelated (though, those scores would be very low). I just need to determine what the "passing grade" is.

For example, for a particular topic, the scores range from 0.009 to .77. Obviously, the document scored at 0.009 is in no way related, and the document scored at .77 is absolutely related.

Is there a statistically correct way to figure out where in that range to place the cut-off?

For example, a crude way might be be to take everything with a score above the mean.  But, this seems crude to me. The way the dataset shakes out, 37.65% of scores are above the mean. Is this a valid method?  Is it the ideal method?

Another way might be to only count documents that are X standard deviations above the mean?  The way things shake out is...

- SD+1: 7.81%
- SD+2: 4.61%
- SD+3: 2.66%
- SD+4: 1.48%
- SD+5: 0.91%

Another option might be to consider those within X standard deviations of the best score?  Here's how that looks:

- > MAX-1SD: 0.01%
- > MAX-2SD: 0.08%
- > MAX-3SD: 0.15%
- > MAX-4SD: 0.28%
- > MAX-5SD: 0.51%
- > MAX-6SD: 0.82%
- > MAX-7SD: 1.30%
- > MAX-8SD: 2.37%
- > MAX-9SD: 3.92%
- > MAX-10SD: 6.77%
- > MAX-11SD: 12.74%

Given this problem, is there some method that can give me some guidance on a decent cut-off point?

**Edit:**

A comment helped me refine what I'm looking for: I want the cut-off *that will minimize both false negatives and false positives as much as possible*.  That line exists somewhere. Is there a statistical way to find it?

Comment: Could you provide more context on the specifics of the problem? Many answers would depend on the specifics of your problem and thus your tolerance for false positives vs. false negatives.

Comment: I don't know what else I could provide....  Software called Mallet has scored 13,378 documents as to their relevance to a specific topic.  I need to figure out at what point the score trail off enough to be consider unrelated.

Comment: For example, how bad is it if you don't identify a document that is actually related to the topic? At the extreme, if someone is going to die because you did not correctly select and review their document, your cutoff is going to be much lower. If you're just interested in getting a sample of the most interesting/relevant topics for research purposes, you could stand a higher cutoff that might miss more of the relevant documents. I don't think this is purely a statistical question (I could be wrong), but I think you need to know those false positive - false negative tradeoffs

Comment: I understand that there will be both false positives and false negatives.  No one will die, but I want to pick a cutoff that minimizes both.  That's key -- I'll update the question with that.